# absolute and relative addressing in gcc inline assembly

Tags: assembly, relative-addressing

I am not able to understand the concept of absolute addressing and relative addressing in assembly particularly in gcc inline assembly. I saw the following code in a tutorial :

```
asm volatile("         \ 
     cli;                 \ 
     mov %0, %%ecx;       \ 
     mov %1, %%esp;       \ 
     mov %2, %%ebp;       \ 
     mov %3, %%cr3;       \ 
     mov $0x12345, %%eax; \ 
     sti;                 \ 
     jmp *%%ecx           "
                : : "r"(eip), "r"(esp), "r"(ebp), "r"(current_directory->physicalAddr));
```

Here the last instruction jmp *%%ecx uses a *. I could not find a good description of what is the significance of the asterisk except that it is used for absolute addressing. I am getting the idea that absolute means actual physical address while relative means offset from the start of the program. However I am not clear about the relative addressing. I read about PC-relative addressing in assembly but i don't understand it completely and it is not clear to me whether relative and PC-relative are same.Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk means nothing. The instruction is invalid without an asterisk. It is an artifact from the AT&T syntax, basically a mnemonic for "load dereferenced value of `ecx` into instruction decoder" which is equivalent to "jump to ecx".

In Intel syntax, the very same instruction would be `jmp ecx`.

There is no instruction for offset jump with the offset distance in an register. The "PC" is called `ip` (instruction pointer) on x86, "relative" without any further context usually means "relative to `ip`".